# Compiling U-BOOT bootloader on x86

Tags: compilation, embedded, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, u-boot

I have download and extracted u-boot-1.1.6 on Ubuntu Linux. I just want to compile the source code using GCC (not targeting cross compilation for any embedded platform).

I tried running the provided `MAKEALL` makefile but "powerpc-linux-gcc : Not Found" is happening.

My understanding is irrespective of platform the source code should compile.

What are the necessary makefile and environment changes I need to do for compilation on x86?

I have taken the recent code. Still facing some issues

I have followed following steps to compile it on x86.

1. `make clean;`
2. `make coreboot-x86_config`
3. `./MAKEALL -C x86`

In step 3 I observed following:

```
ravitiwari@RAVI-HP-Pavilion-dv2000-GJ175PA-ACJ:~/u-boot-2013.04$ make clean
ravitiwari@RAVI-HP-Pavilion-dv2000-GJ175PA-ACJ:~/u-boot-2013.04$ make coreboot-x86_config
Configuring for coreboot-x86 - Board: coreboot, Options: SYS_TEXT_BASE=0x01110000
ravitiwari@RAVI-HP-Pavilion-dv2000-GJ175PA-ACJ:~/u-boot-2013.04$ ./MAKEALL -C x86
Configuring for coreboot-x86 - Board: coreboot, Options: SYS_TEXT_BASE=0x01110000
    make[1]: ** [interrupts.o] Error 127
    make: ** [arch/x86/cpu/libx86.o] Error 2
    make[1]: ** [coreboot.o] Error 127
    make: ** [arch/x86/cpu/coreboot/libcoreboot.o] Error 2
    make[1]: ** [bootm.o] Error 127
    make: ** [arch/x86/lib/libx86.o] Error 2
    size: './u-boot': No such file
    /bin/bash: sparse: command not found
    make[1]: ** [interrupts.o] Error 127
    make: ** [arch/x86/cpu/libx86.o] Error 2
    make: ** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    /bin/bash: sparse: command not found
    make[1]: ** [coreboot.o] Error 127
    make: ** [arch/x86/cpu/coreboot/libcoreboot.o] Error 2
    /bin/bash: sparse: command not found
    make[1]: ** [bootm.o] Error 127
    make: ** [arch/x86/lib/libx86.o] Error 2
    make: INTERNAL: Exiting with 4 jobserver tokens available; should be 3!

    --------------------- SUMMARY ----------------------------

    Boards compiled: 1
    Boards with errors: 1( coreboot-x86 )
```

Comment: The more important question might be what are you hoping to achieve by compiling this without a particular target?

Answer (score 2):

make clean; make coreboot-x86_config; make 
is more likely to be useful to you.

In my experience, u-boot is built for a single *specific* embedded platform. That would be true even when your host is x86, so you have /usr/bin/gcc already installed.

What you stumbled on (I see it by running ./MAKEALL at top level) wants to build ALL of the embedded platforms available. But it will still build specific platforms, that is inherent to U-Boot mission. It defaulted to using powerpc toolchain (powerpc-linux-gcc) rather than the x86 toolchain. My suggestion instead chooses a specific x86-based platform, and builds it. You will see various compilation outputs at console, showing what's going on.

MAKEALL would build, then throw away build results, for multiple other platforms first. You could do 
.MAKEALL -c x86
but that hides compilation outputs. For other CPU you'd need appropriate cross compiler installed.

Comment: Thanks Joe, Still facing some issues:

Comment: Steps Followed:

1) make clean 
2)make coreboot-x86_config 
3)./MAKEALL -C x86 . 

In step 1  bfin-elf-gcc: Command not found came. 
In step 2 make: bfin-elf-gcc: Command not found
make: *** No rule to make target `coreboot-x86_config'. 
In Step 3 make: bfin-elf-gcc: Command not found
make: *** _config: No such file or directory.  Stop.
System not configured - see README
make: *** [all] Error 1

I tried with other include/configs also but Since i am new to bootloader i am not able to figure whats wrong. Please explain?

Comment: Looks like maybe you have environment variable set up for cross compiling with blackfin. "printenv | grep CROSS_COMPILE" would show that. If so, clear it. Also maybe useful, "which gcc"; IIRC my linux gave /usr/bin/gcc, and the x86 u-boot targets built ok.

Comment: I checked for environment variable and its is not set to blackfin and "which gcc" also showed same way as in yours : /usr/bin/gcc.

Comment: There are two environmental variables to look out for 1) ARCH 2) CROSS_COMPILE. 1) Unset both the env variables  2) remove the cross compile tool chain link from PATH env variable 3) Check if any of these env variables "PATH, ARCH and CROSS_COMPILE" exported in your .bashrc file, present under home directory, if so comment those lines and try building it.